# How do i add Input transformation to a target using aws cdk for a cloudwatch event rule?

Tags: aws-cdk

After i create a cloud-watch event rule i am trying to add a target to it but i am unable to add a input transformation. Previously the add target had the props allowed for input transformation but it does not anymore.

```
codeBuildRule.addTarget(new SnsTopic(props.topic));
```

The aws cdk page provides this solution but i dont exactly understand what it says

You can add additional targets, with optional input transformer using eventRule.addTarget(target[, input]). For example, we can add a SNS topic target which formats a human-readable message for the commit.

Answer (score 19):

You should specify the `message` prop and use `RuleTargetInput` [static methods](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-events.RuleTargetInput.html#static-from-wbr-event-wbr-pathpath). Some of these methods can use strings returned by [`EventField.fromPath()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-events.EventField.html#static-from-wbr-pathpath):

```ts
// From a path
codeBuildRule.addTarget(new SnsTopic(props.topic, {
  message: events.RuleTargetInput.fromEventPath('$.detail')
}));

// Custom object
codeBuildRule.addTarget(new SnsTopic(props.topic, {
  message: RuleTargetInput.fromObject({
    foo: EventField.fromPath('$.detail.bar')
  })
}));
```

Comment: In my case with a lambda as a target I had to use the **event** prop:

`rule.addTarget(new LambdaFunction(lambdaFunction, {event: RuleTargetInput.fromObject({customEvent: 'Hello'})}));`

Answer (score 7):

I had the same question trying to implement this tutorial in CDK: [Tutorial: Set up a CloudWatch Events rule to receive email notifications for pipeline state changes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/tutorials-cloudwatch-sns-notifications.html)

I found this helpful as well: [Detect and react to changes in pipeline state with Amazon CloudWatch Events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/detect-state-changes-cloudwatch-events.html)

NOTE: I could not get it to work using the Pipeline's class method onStateChange().

I ended up writing a Rule:

```
const topic = new Topic(this, 'topic', {topicName: 'codepipeline-notes-failure',
});

const description = `Generated by the CDK for stack: ${this.stackName}`;
new Rule(this, 'failed', {
  description: description,
  eventPattern: {
    detail: {state: ['FAILED'], pipeline: ['notes']},
    detailType: ['CodePipeline Pipeline Execution State Change'],
    source: ['aws.codepipeline'],
  },
  targets: [
    new SnsTopic(topic, {
      message: RuleTargetInput.fromText(
        `The Pipeline '${EventField.fromPath('$.detail.pipeline')}' has ${EventField.fromPath(
          '$.detail.state',
        )}`,
      ),
    }),
  ],
});
```

After implementing, if you navigate to Amazon EventBridge -> Rules, then select the rule, then select the Target(s) and then click View Details you will see the Target Details with the Input transformer & InputTemplate.

> Input transformer:
> {"InputPathsMap":{"detail-pipeline":"$.detail.pipeline","detail-state":"$.detail.state"},"InputTemplate":"\"The
> Pipeline '<detail-pipeline>' has <detail-state>\""}

Comment: It appears with "\" in the events->rules->target message. How to avoid this?

Comment: thank you. python version of the above code:--
yourRule.add_target(target=targets.SnsTopic(topic=snstopicName, message=events.RuleTargetInput.from_text(f"""The job with name {events.EventField.from_path('$.detail.jobName')} failed  with the the job run id {events.EventField.from_path('$.detail.jobRunId')}. add more if you want to """
)))

Comment: @PruthviRaj could you make a new answer with the python version

Comment: How about a string with new-lines?

Answer (score 1):

This would work for CDK Python. CodeBuild to SNS notifications.

```py
sns_topic = sns.Topic(...)
codebuild_project = codebuild.Project(...)
sns_topic.grant_publish(codebuild_project)
codebuild_project.on_build_failed(
            f'rule-on-failed',
            target=events_targets.SnsTopic(
                sns_topic,
                message=events.RuleTargetInput.from_multiline_text(
                    f"""
                    Name: {events.EventField.from_path('$.detail.project-name')} 
                    State: {events.EventField.from_path('$.detail.build-status')}
                    Build: {events.EventField.from_path('$.detail.build-id')}
                    Account: {events.EventField.from_path('$.account')}
                """
                )
            )
        )
```

Credits to @pruthvi-raj comment on an answer above